# How to assign background-image url dynamically with only html and css?

Tags: html, css, css-variables

I'm trying to assign the `url` of `background-image` dynamically though css from the attributes defined on html tags. But it seems neither `attr()` nor `var()` works. I'm avoiding to use javascript because the url might change later so I have to trigger that script manually again.

Is there a better solution for this?

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.normal, .attr, .var {
  flex: 1;
  height: 240px;
  border: solid 1px #666;
  background-size: cover;
}

.normal {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/320/240");
}

.attr {
  background-image: url(attr(data-bg));
}

.var {
  background-image: url(var(--url));
}
```

```html
<div class="normal"></div>
<div class="attr" data-bg="https://picsum.photos/320/240"></div>
<div class="var" style="--url: 'https://picsum.photos/320/240';"></div>
```

Even more, I wish I can concatenate the string if it's possible.

```css
.image {
  border: solid 1px #666;
  width: 320px;
  height: 240px;
  /* I wish this is possible */
  background-image: url("http://www.example.com/images/" attr(data-bg) ".png");
}
```

```html
<div class="image" data-bg="adorable_cat"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if I feel like it would be much easier to do with simply using inline `background-image` property (especially if you want to concatenate url string). For simple use you can do that like that:

```
<div class="var" style="--url: url(https://picsum.photos/320/240)"></div>

.var {
  background-image: var(--url);
}
```

For reasons unclear for me, using `url(var(--url));` doesn't seem to be working at all (at least at Chrome)

Comment: This is a good one :D

Comment: FYI, this is the reason you can't use `url(var(--url))`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42331003/6962

Answer (score -1):

Put an embedded stylesheet in the document's :

```
<style type="text/css">
.logo
{
background: #FFF url(<?php echo $variable_holding_img_url; ?>);
}
</style>
```

for more information

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303891/how-to-have-dynamic-image-as-css-background)

[How to have dynamic image as CSS background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303891/how-to-have-dynamic-image-as-css-background)